# Animating a Control using a sine wave

Tags: c#, controls

On my form is a control. What I would like to do is animate this control using a Sine wave so that the control itself could look like its floating upward like a balloon. I am horrible with math which is probably not a good thing with programming but was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how I should tackle this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to use the Sin wave to generate some nice flowing values for you.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= 180 ; i ++ ){
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Sin(Math.PI * i / 180));
}
```

You can adjust the above to suit your needs...

If you only need to go up (like a balloon) then you can stop at 90 rather than 180.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= 90 ; i ++ ){
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Sin(Math.PI * i / 180));
}
```

If you need more steps (a smaller increment) then you can make i into a double and increment by halves or quarters.

```
for(double i = 0 ; i <= 90 ; i += .5 ){
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Sin(Math.PI * i / 180));
}
```

All of the above will give you a range of values between 0 and 1. You can multiply this value by 100 if your control requires an integer..